# Nvidia Card not recognized

Tags: nvidia

I have a Lenovo T420 with the on board Intel graphics card and the Nvidia 4300M but Ubuntu only sees the on board card.  Any idea how to get it to see the Nvidia card?

Thanks

Comment: does it use NVidia Optimus technology?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an Optimus system. Ubuntu currently doesn't support switching between graphics cards.

But there are workarounds. You're probably going to want to look at the [Ironhide project](https://launchpad.net/~mj-casalogic/+archive/ironhide/). It's an extension of an earlier project that uses your Intel graphics for most thing and then uses offscreen rendering (via virtualgl on your nvidia card) for the hardcore 3D.

It's certainly an interesting idea and as far as I know, there currently isn't a better solution.